# Group a list of originals into list of lists by key based on dictionary of its copies

Tags: c#, list, grouping

I have a `List<Route> targetroutes`

and I have a dictionary of the same routes (their copies)

```
IDictionary<int,IList<Route>>  finalsetofCombinations
```

I need to group targetroutes into `List<List<Route>>Routes`
The same way their copies are grouped in the dictionary
A do not need copies in the `List<List<Route>>Routes`
I need grouped originals

Comment: What? Can you please explain more clearly? Please include class definitions and sample data (in valid C# code) and the expect output.

Comment: targetroutes is a list of some originals. finalsetofCombinations  - dictionary that contains copies of the same objects of the class <Route> as in the List<Route> targetroutes. I need to transform List<Route> into List<List<Route>>Routes where subdivision is performed the same way as  subdivision of copies in dictionary

Comment: What? Can you please explain more clearly? **Please include class definitions and sample data (in valid C# code) and the expected output.** Please edit your question with these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is not an issue, perhaps something like this would do:

```
var listOfLists = dictionary
    .Select(pair => pair.Value
        .Select(copy => list
            .First(original => original == copy)) // insert proper equality check
        .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seem working! By the way, does  such expression seriously reduces performance and what are the alternatives if you need to do such grouping?

Comment: Well, LINQ is generally not super fast. Also, we are going through the original list every time, which is pretty inefficient (that would be the first thing I'd try to get rid of). But unless you have a LOT of items or do this at critical times, the speed honestly shouldn't matter.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for help!

Comment: @MichalS - The `.Select(copy => list.First(original => original == copy))` appears to basically do nothing. If `original == copy` then it's the same as `.Select(copy => copy)` (unless `list` doesn't contain copy then in that case the `.First(...)` will throw an exception).

Comment: @Enigmativity Hence the "insert proper equality check" comment, as in compare by ID or whatever makes sense. Author specifically mentioned that the dictionary contains copies but he wants originals from the list.